# Combine All CSVs in Folder then Delete First 3 Column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I am trying to combine multiple CSVs in a folder then delete the first 3 columns. My code combines the files ok but I can't drop the columns. Can anyone see the issue?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\****' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

frame.drop(frame.columns[[0, 1, 2]], axis=1)

print(frame)
frame.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Can’t you just read_csv without the first 3 columns `usecols`, with use `pd.read_csv('foo.csv', usecols=[3:])`?

Comment: You need to assign it back, `frame = frame.drop(frame.columns[[0, 1, 2]], axis=1)` is one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `. iloc[:,3]`  and select the columns index you desire:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

path = Path('C:\Users\****') # use your path
all_files = path.glob("*.csv")

frame = pd.concat(
(pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=0).iloc[:,3:]
for file_ in all_files), axis=0, ignore_index=True)

frame.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Mmh! In Pandas context, it means all columns minus first 3. Columns are a list of index or actual names

Comment: I will find a PC. Mustafa, I think you are correct. I read documents and it appears that is is not a list list as order does not matter

Comment: Okay, change to `.iloc[:, 3:]` this will read all columns then select all but first three. Everything remains the same